# The ampersand operator with parameters

Tags: ruby

I wonder, isn't it possible to call a method using & operator with parameters?

```
items.each &:my_proc # ok
items.each &:my_proc(123, "456") # ops!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Use full form.

```
items.each{|i| i.my_proc(123, '456')}
```

Look at the source of [Symbol#to_proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) for the "why".

Comment: looked, but didn't find the reason why. would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: Because it's not implemented :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bit of trickery and acheive something similar:

```
class Symbol
  def [](*args)
    proc{|obj| obj.send(self, *args) }
  end
end

[123.456, 234.567].map(&:round[2])
#=> [123.46, 234.57]
```

I highly discourage the use in production code though, since gems etc may rely on `Symbol#[]`. This is just a fun thing to play around with ;-)

Comment: Nice.  You could use, e.g., `bind_args` instead of `[]`.  Although not as pretty to use, it'd be safer in production code.

Comment: That's true. But then again i prefer standards over magic and the form suggested by @SergioTulentsev is better suited.

Comment: Actually `map{|x| x.round(2)}` is even shorter and better to read than `map(&:round.bind_args(2))` :)